# How to submit a OSX 10.7 application compatible with 10.6?

Tags: macos, app-store, backwards-compatibility, mac-app-store

I want to build an OSX application that will use some of the new 10.7 SDK features (more specifically, In-App purchases). However I don't want to completely prevent 10.6 users from installing the application.

How can I make it so that 10.7 users have access to the new features, and 10.6 users simply don't have the new features but can still use the basic stuff?

When I compile for 10.6 it doesn't load the SDK that has "InApp", as expected. And I suppose if I compile for 10.7 users won't be able to install it from the AppStore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of [these](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000067.php) methods to determine the user's OS version, then if they are running Lion, run the code, if they aren't don't run it (use an if statement)

Edit: You'll also have to weak link the storekit framework

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but for newer API's (such as those for Lion only) I just use an IF statement with respondToSelector:

This is one of the way suggested by Apple and you don't have to mess with knowing a particular OS during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Could you create a bundle that could get loaded and offer the 10.7 features?  Your real app could check to see which OS it's running under and not load the 10.7 bundle.  I don't know if this would work since it wouldn't be unreasonable for a 10.7-SDK bundle to refuse to load in a 10.6 SDK app.

Another possibility might be to have two apps under the hood, and have a very small shell app (possibly even a script) that detects the host OS and execs the OS-correct executable.

Comment: Would those methods be compatible with the AppStore submission?

Comment: Sorry...I don't know.  I don't know the details of AppStore qualifications.  I was merely trying to think through the technical issues rather than the business/political issues.